# Minecraft pe will not load

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues

I have been playing Minecraft pe for over two years now and it has become one of my most favorite games. I recently created a Xbox live account to be able to play on servers. Everything seemed fine until yesterday. Apple came out with a new version of iOS and I updated my device. Now, I can’t load the game, the screen that says Minecraft after mojang goes to the last three or four bars then freezes. Nothing else happens. If I go to airplane mode I can launch the game but shortly after that it will crash. Does anyone know what’s wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, but eventually it does load for me. Maybe you should wait until it does load? (It takes 25-35 minutes for me to load it, though).

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me with one of my games once. I had to reinstall the game and everything worked fine.

Comment: Will I lose my worlds?

Comment: My game data was fine. Not sure about Minecraft but it's probably the same.

Comment: Ok, I tried several different ways to fix the problem from backing it up on iCloud to uninstalling and reinstalling Minecraft so far. The iCloud backup saved the previous version and that version seems to be corrupt. I’ve accessed minecraft’s files on my iOS and I think I messed somethings up when I did. I don’t know what I should do.

Comment: Maybe you can offload the app?